# Windows 8 Store certification for a Windows Desktop App written in Java

Tags: java, windows, windows-store, windows-store-apps

I have a program that is written in Java and is wrapped by an installer. It requires Java 1.7. If I run the certification with "Windows App Certification" it passes with one warning for the case Java 1.7 is already installed. But if Java 1.7 is not installed the certification stops, as the installer will ask for the Java installation.

Does someone know if it is possible to add this Java app to the Windows store?

Unfortunately I haven't found any information on that. I could just go for the certification, but If Microsoft would not accept it, it would not be worth the effort.

After a view phone calls and emails it seems that even Microsoft itself seems not be able to answer this questions :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be able to distribute for a Windows Desktop App you have to create an company account, which is quite a process.

Than you have to create that Desktop Dashboard account. There you have to sign a file from Microsoft with your certificate. But is has to be a specific certificate only from Verisign. This is ridiculous! I already have a valid certificate, why should I just for that freaking Windows Store buy a new certificate.

With all that I still don't know if Microsoft will be so kind to allow Desktop Apps written in Java. No wonder there are not many Apps in the Windows Store!

Comment: same experience here, and all this just to display a link to your website on the store search results!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to install a lower version of Java Engine lower than version 1.7? You may try to do that, and if need arises that you need to install the 1.7 for the certification to work, it will download it online if you are connected constantly to the internet during installation. Also, check if your Windows OS is not corrupt or compromised. Bad or errors in Windows registry do cause all these type of things, thereby not allowing the system to know that java 1.7 exists

Comment: On some Windows machine there is no Java pre-installed. Also the Java program needs the 1.7. The questions is more general: If Microsoft allows any Java program in their Windows store as a Desktop App.

Answer (score 1):

in a mail Microsoft told me they do allow Java programs as Desktop apps.

"After a thorough investigation, we came up with the understanding that, you can publish java running apps as desktop apps only. You will need to sign up as a company in order to do so. The reason that you can publish java running apps as desktop apps is due to the fact that desktop apps are usually just "advertised" in the store. The description page usually contains a link that brings you to the developer's webpage in order for you to download the app. It is different from windows 8 apps that can be directly downloaded from the store. Please let me know if this answers your question.

Sincerely,

Joel ** (name removed for his privacy (olivier))

** @microsoft.com

4697756905

Monday: 8 AM to 5 PM CST

Tue-Fri: 1 PM to 10 PM CST

Tier 3 Marketplace Escalation Engineer

Microsoft Las Colinas  "

Comment: This is interesting, as I got told from support that it is not allowed. The question is, do you need to bundle Java VM with your APP? Which would be a license problem. Have you tried it? We did not try, as you also need to buy and use the special certificate from Mircrosoft and Symantec.

Comment: For now I do not think it is necessary. When testing my app with the ToolKit there were no warnings / failures coming up that a Java VM is missing. I am in the process of trying right now. After this automated test it will be tested by actual people from microsoft too when I submit it to them. Then the need to pack a Java VM might come up anyway. When I know more I will update this answer.

Comment: @FMolivierH Do you still not know more? ;)

Comment: Time flies! I do know that I was never prompted to add a Java VM, so there was no need to add it then. However, a few months ago I got notice from Microsoft that they were kicking my app out for some reason. If I recall correct because they only want to accept native Windows apps, but I'm not sure. I'll check the exact reason out and will get back on this when I know more...

Answer (score 0):

Many years after. But for someone reaching this question like me. Now exists Project Centennial which allows to pack your win32 app and publish it to the store.

Just pack your application along with the jvm in an installer and use Project Centennial to convert it in an appx and them upload to the store.

It only works in Windows 10 Anniversary Update

**Update**

- 2016-01-06: Windows Store now includes the DesktopAppConverter: https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9nblggh4skzw
- 2016-01-06: InstallShield now can generate APPX from your regular instalation using ProjectCentennial: http://blogs.flexerasoftware.com/installtalk/project-centennial/

Regards

Comment: I packed the application and installed as a side loading Windows Store App. But I didn't uploaded it to Windows Store. Look for DesktopAppConverter in Windows Store