# Submit desktop app to Windows 8 store with code singing

Tags: windows-8, windows-store, code-signing-certificate

I know this needs Code Signing Certificate. Just wonder if it must be the Code Signing Certificate from VeriSign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certification requirements for the Windows Store (Desktop Apps) mandates that files are signed with an Authenticode certificate, but doesn't specify which CA. Based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj256845.aspx I would say that as long as its a reputable code-signing certificate (not self-signed, or a private CA) then it would pass certification.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to be Verisign, also according to Michael S: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13026302/921282

Also from first hand. I got the next quote when testing with Microsoft development kit. (You get the link to this information only when the test passes without FAILURE. The site is restricted and shows to MS services users only)

WARNING Install signed driver and executable files

"VeriSign Code-Signing Certificates for Microsoft Authenticode  ($99 USD)
The Microsoft Authenticode certificate provided by VeriSign is the only accepted method of authentication, file signing, and code-signing. Microsoft will not be able to accept any other authentication method, including GeoTrust authentication required by the Windows Store. "